# Gson parsing text/plain by object model doesn't isolate field but prints all

Tags: java, json, gson, htmlunit

I have a String containing `json` data in `text/plain` format which was returned by a web response. I'm trying to get a specific value from **mail** key through Google's **Gson** library. However, after following some examples in google I still can't get the value for mail. Instead, it returns all data contained in String.

```
public class EmailData {
    public String mail;

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }
}
```

The response returned via a link has the ff (`text/plain`). This is what's shown on browser and console.

```
{
  "search": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "dn": "uid=C12345678,c=ph,ou=pages,o=website.com",
        "attribute": [
          {
            "name": "mail",
            "value": [
              "myemail123@website.com"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "employeecountrycode",
            "value": [
              "818"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "dept",
            "value": [
              "ABC"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "return": {
          "code": 0,
          "message": "Success",
          "count": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to be able to get just the value for `mail` which is **myemail123@website.com**

So what I tried is this.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String linkReturningJsonTextPlain = "http://....";
    try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient();){
        Page page = webClient.getPage(linkReturningJsonTextPlain);
        WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
        String jsonString = response.getContentAsString();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        EmailData emailData = gson.fromJson(jsonString, EmailData.class);
        System.out.println(emailData.getMail());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get all the data contained in `jsonString` instead of just **myemail123@website.com**.

What am I doing wrong? I followed all examples. I get text/plain when I print `response.getContentType()`

My last option now is to do the manual splitting and substring(ing) of the json String.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your json format you cannot convert EmailData class back. The json format should be `{"mail":"mail@example.com"}`

Consider the code:

EmailData class.

```
package gson;

public class EmailData {

    private String mail;

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmailData{" +
               "mail='" + mail + '\'' +
               '}';
    }
}
```

Test class for showing how Gson converts

```
package gson;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        EmailData emailData = new EmailData();
        emailData.setMail("mail@example.com");

        String toJson = gson.toJson(emailData);

        System.out.println("toJson = " + toJson);

        EmailData fromJson = gson.fromJson(toJson, EmailData.class);
        System.out.println("fromJson = " + fromJson);
    }
}
```

In this example I am converting EmailData class to json and back. For solving your problem I recommend you to use whether Regular expression or Json for extraction email like shown in this post [How to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json) and the create an EmailData class manually via constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as reference to those who might encounter problems pulling record from a bunch of keys with `array` values contained in **json** response.

Given the **json** data in text format above, this is how I got the value from **mail** element.

```
JsonArray attribute_Array = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("search").
            getAsJsonArray("entry").get(0).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("attribute");
String email = "not found";
for (JsonElement e : attribute_Array) {
    String key = e.getAsJsonObject().get("name").toString().replace("\"", "");
    if(key.equals("mail")){
        email = e.getAsJsonObject().get("value").toString();
    }
}
```

email, whose initial value is "**not found**" will be replaced by whatever value the json element mail contains.

As you can see, both `entry` and `attribute` was passed as argument to `getAsJsonArray()` because both has arrays of values.

I'm sure this will help others who might get confused in pulling values from nested arrays within Json.

Thanks to @Velaniv Jr, the link you provided helped.